# how to line break in siunitx while align numbers at decimal point

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I managed to align all numbers in a row at the decimal point with this

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}        
\usepackage{microtype}              
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}           
\usepackage{xfrac}                  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}                   
\usepackage{caption}                
\usepackage{siunitx}                


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} 
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}} 
\begin{document}   
\begin{table}[h!]    
\setcapmargin*{0.10cm}      
\caption[Übersicht aller PV-Anlagen im Testnetz \textit{Uniwohngebiet}]{Übersicht aller PV-Anlagen im Testnetz \textit{Uniwohngebiet}}  
\small
\centering
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {.}}
\begin{tabular}{L{3.5cm} S C{3.5cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}} 
\toprule
\textbf{PV-Einspeisezähler Bezeichnung SWK} & \textbf{Installierte PV-Leistung [$\SI{}{\textbf{kW}}$]} & \textbf{Südausrichtung [°]}  & \textbf{Gruppe} & \textbf{Gemessen}\\ % \textbf{[W]}
\midrule
VNBE014220                  & 3.69  & 16 & 1 & x\\
VNBE014469                  & 11.47 & 16 & 1 & \\
VNBE015412                  & 3.51  & 16 & 1 & x\\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:Uebersicht_PV}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But how can force a line break of the header of the second row?

If i use   `\begin{tabular}{L{3.5cm} C{3cm} C{3.5cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}}` 
instead of `\begin{tabular}{L{3.5cm} S C{3.5cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}}` i can make the linebreak with `\textbf{Installierte PV-\newline Leistung [$\SI{}{\textbf{kW}}$]}`.

Thank you :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please post a complete minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}` including all necessary packages and definitions to compile your code and show your issue but *not* more than that. In your code we do not know how you defined `\gls` and how the column definition of `C` and `L` is.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it

Comment: Your numbers are not aligned at the decimal marker!

Comment: my bad. srry. never wrote something here before. no i've got it!

Comment: off topic, but if you want to typeset only the units, I would use something like`\si[detect-all]{\kilo\watt}` instead of `\SI{}{\textbf{kW}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `\thead{...}` command from the `makecell` package. Please note that the command has to be enclosed in `{}` in order to communicate to siunitx that that this cell is not a number.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}        
\usepackage{microtype}              
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}           
\usepackage{xfrac}                  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}                   
\usepackage{caption}                
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{makecell}        


\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}              

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}   

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htbp]        
\caption[Übersicht aller PV-Anlagen im Testnetz \textit{Uniwohngebiet}]{Übersicht aller PV-Anlagen im Testnetz \textit{Uniwohngebiet}}
\label{tab:Uebersicht_PV}  
\small
\centering
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {.}}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} S @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c @{}} 
\toprule
{\thead{PV-Einspeisezähler\\ Bezeichnung SWK}} & {\thead{Installierte\\ PV-Leistung [\si[detect-all]{kW}]}} & {\thead{Südausrichtung [°]}}  & {\thead{Gruppe}} & {\thead{Gemessen}}\\ 
\midrule
VNBE014220                  & 3.69  & 16 & 1 & x\\
VNBE014469                  & 11.47 & 16 & 1 & \\
VNBE015412                  & 3.51  & 16 & 1 & x\\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was just about to post a `makecell` answer :(

Comment: @Skillmon Oh, I am sorry!

Comment: No problem :) But one should mention, that the surrounding `{}` in the `S`-column are important for correct alignment.

Comment: @Skillmon without the `{}` siunitx will anyway throw an error.

Comment: Last question: How do I set the width of every row now?

Comment: @P.Maino By using your origional code with `C{3.5cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}`. I personally prefer to let latex determine the width as this will ensure equal spaces between the columns.

Comment: @samcarter That works for L and C but not for S. I prefer when every picture and table is as wide as the text.

Comment: @P.Maino Please see my edited answer - I really think hard coded widths are the wrong way to achieve a table that fills the whole textwidth!

Comment: You are absolutely right! I wasn't aware of that command! I'll use it in the future! :)

Comment: @Samcarter When I'm using `\thead` the distance to the the toprule and the midrule increases. Do you know how i can handle that?

Comment: @P.Maino Please don't ask new questions in comments.